# Disabled checkboxes should not be checked when select all checkbox is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a grid with a few items which have a checkbox at the start of each row. I also have a select all checkbox at the top of the grid. The scenario is something like our gmail or yahoo inbox. My question is, suppose i disable a checkbox and then click on select all checkbox, the disabled checkbox should not be checked. Is there any solution for this? I have attached relevant pieces of code as follows.

***aspx file**

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn">

     <HeaderTemplate>

         <asp:CheckBox id="headerChkbox" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>

     </HeaderTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection" AutoPostBack="True"  runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>

     </ItemTemplate>

</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

***code behind**

```
 protected void ToggleRowSelection(object sender, EventArgs e) //selecting a particular row

    {
        ((sender as CheckBox).NamingContainer as GridItem).Selected = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;

    }

    protected void ToggleSelectedState(object sender, EventArgs e) //select all rows

    {

        CheckBox headerCheckBox = (sender as CheckBox);

        foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in grdCurrent.MasterTableView.Items)

        {

            (dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked = headerCheckBox.Checked;

            dataItem.Selected = headerCheckBox.Checked;

        }

    }
```

Comment: so you want to select all except the selected before "select All" is clicked??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if it is `Enabled` before setting it to Checked.

```
CheckBox headerCheckBox = (sender as CheckBox);

foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in grdCurrent.MasterTableView.Items)
{
  if((dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Enabled) // add this condtion
  {
    (dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked = headerCheckBox.Checked;
    dataItem.Selected = headerCheckBox.Checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it was not possible to achieve it through code-behind. was thinking big about jquery and all. thanks for your solution buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using code behind to select all. I will use javascript or Jquery to do it. My method will be applying different css class for enabled and disabled checkbox like "enabled" and "disabled". In Jquery, I check the class and only tick the enabled checkboxes.